# Userfaultfd doesn't receive fork event unless a register is done before

Tags: linux, rust, fork

I'm creating a program that uses [`userfaultfd`](https://docs.rs/userfaultfd/0.5.1/userfaultfd/index.html) to manipulate some pages of child processes. I need this program to monitor all child programs, so I'm listening for forks with `EVENT_FORK`. However, this doesn't work unless I first `register` a dummy page:

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
nix = "0.26.2"
rustix = { version = "0.37.3", features = ["mm"] }
userfaultfd = "0.5.1"
```

main.rs:

```rust
use {nix::unistd, rustix::mm, std::ptr};

fn main() {
    // Allocate a "dummy" page for uffd to register
    println!("Allocating dummy page");
    let dummy_page_size = 4096;
    let dummy_page = unsafe {
        mm::mmap_anonymous(
            ptr::null_mut(),
            dummy_page_size,
            mm::ProtFlags::READ | mm::ProtFlags::WRITE,
            mm::MapFlags::PRIVATE,
        )
        .expect("Unable to allocate memory")
    };

    // Initialize uffd
    println!("Building uffd");
    let uffd = userfaultfd::UffdBuilder::new()
        .require_features(userfaultfd::FeatureFlags::EVENT_FORK)
        .require_ioctls(userfaultfd::IoctlFlags::empty())
        .close_on_exec(false)
        .user_mode_only(true)
        .non_blocking(false)
        .create()
        .expect("Unable to create uffd");

    // Perform a dummy register to fully initialize the uffd.
    println!("Registering dummy page");
    uffd.register(dummy_page, dummy_page_size)
        .expect("Unable to perform dummy register");

    // Fork on a separate thread
    let _ = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Forking");
        match unsafe { unistd::fork().expect("Unable to fork") } {
            // On the parent, wait for the child
            unistd::ForkResult::Parent { child } => {
                println!("Waiting for child {child}");
                let _ = nix::sys::wait::wait().expect("Unable to wait for child");
                println!("Child {child} exited");
            },

            // On the child, execute the command
            unistd::ForkResult::Child => {
                println!("Executing child");
                std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
            },
        }
    });

    println!("Entering uffd event loop");
    while let Some(event) = uffd.read_event().expect("Unable to read event") {
        println!("Event: {event:?}");
    }
    println!("Exiting uffd event loop");
}
```

Outputs:

```
Allocating dummy page
Building uffd
Registering dummy page
Entering uffd event loop
Forking
Event: Fork { uffd: Uffd { fd: 4 } }
Waiting for child 228151
Executing child
Child 228151 exited
```

The important being the `Event: Fork { uffd: Uffd { fd: 4 } }` event that was received.

Without the `uffd.register(dummy_page, dummy_page_size)` part, the following is output (regardless of whether the `mmap` allocation occurs or not)

```
Allocating dummy page
Building uffd
Registering dummy page
Entering uffd event loop
Forking
Waiting for child 228349
Executing child
Child 228349 exited
```

Which doesn't contain the fork event. Why is this?

Even with the dummy register, if the child process itself forks, no fork event is received.
I haven't tested whether or not doing a register write in the child would work, but I suspect that'd allow me to see the child's fork.

When running, I use `sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=ep ./target/debug/...` to be able to run the program, if relevant.

Performing an invalid register like `uffd.register(std::ptr::null_mut(), 0).unwrap_err()` results in no fork event.

When doing the dummy register, the `fork` call is stopped until `read_event` occurs in the main thread.
When not doing the dummy register, the `fork` does not wait at all.

Comment: According to the [`userfaultfd(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) man page: "*if the faulting process invokes `fork(2)`, the userfaultfd objects associated with the parent may be duplicated into the child process and the userfaultfd monitor will be notified (via the `UFFD_EVENT_FORK` described below) about the file descriptor associated with the userfault objects created for the child process*".  To my reading: if no userfault objects have been registered, none will be duplicated into the child and thus no fork notification will be issued.

Comment: @eggyal I assumed by "userfaultfd objects" it means the `Uffd` object I created (i.e. it's underlying file descriptor), not registered memory ranges

Comment: Hm.  Yeah, that does appear to be the correct interpretation.  [This](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/893e26e61d04eac974ded0c11e1647b335c8cb7b) is the (relatively small) kernel commit that added the feature... I'm just trying to work out what it's doing in practice.

Comment: It [looks to me](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/893e26e61d04eac974ded0c11e1647b335c8cb7b#diff-e37b5cb4c23f6ab27741c60ec48674eff0268624a228c9a1cddddb9e4ee2922dR622) like userfaultfd objects are maintained per mmap region, and it is those that are duplicated into the child?  In which case, no mmap regions = no duplication.  Bit out of my depth here though, tbf.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for the help regardless. I've decided to scrap this approach and use a `ptrace` approach, where I can then create the uffd on the child and pass it over to the parent with `pidfd_getfd`.